# How to make a mob spawner that spawns mobs at a specific coordinate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I have noticed this method used in older maps, I am playing in 1.17.1, and I was wondering if there is any way to make a mob spawner spawn the entity, in my case, a piece of smooth stone, at a specific coordinate.

The reason I want to know this is for the sake of Redstone, I would like to summon a single piece of stone on a pressure plate by using a mob spawner.

Comment: Does this have to be done explicitly using spawners?

Comment: Not really, the idea is that a player walks into a room and there is a spawner that they cannot see which summons an item to activate a pressure plate, basically making it to where something happens just from them walking into a room or over a specific spot

Comment: Shouldn't `/summon` do what you want? Why do you need a spawner?

Comment: it's so a player walks into a room and a command is run just by them being there, essentially there is a spawner above them that activates when they walk into an area

Answer (score 1):

I tested to change a spawner to spawn stone as an item but it didn't seem to spawn anything.

However, you can use the `execute` command to test when a player enters a specific area:

`execute if entity @a[x=-61,y=56,z=65,dx=2,dy=1,dz=2] run "Your command"`

You could then remove the `stone pressure plate` and use this command:

`setblock x y z redstone_block`

or you could also summon the wanted stone:

`/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"stone",Count:1}}`

---

Whitin `@a[x=-61,y=56,z=65,dx=2,dy=1,dz=2]` you would place your own `x y z` and the `dx dy dz` is how far it tests for.

this:

`execute if entity @a[x=-61,y=56,z=65,dx=2,dy=1,dz=2]`

Will test for all players at a cube from `-61 56 65` to `-59 57 67`